# How can I get stream data from new Google Analytics 4 API?

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have a few research related to Google Analytics, especially the new version GA4; however, I have no idea **"how to stream the data from this?"**.
Does anybody have experience with this?

Please answer my question, I'll be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) can be used to extract data from Google analytics GA4 accounts.

It is currently the only API available for extracting data from GA4 at the time of writing this api is in beta so take that into account when developing production applications.

There is also a client library for python [client-libraries#python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/client-libraries#python)